# what is the best introduction to gaussion process regression?

Tags: machine-learning

i seached and found that there are quite a few documents introducing Gaussion Process Regression. I picked up one but it seems to be too brief and I still could not understand what is GPR. Anyone has experience and direct to one or some good tutorial?

Comment: So... you're giving up your research because the first document out of many that you found was too brief...?

Comment: @Amos I know what you mean. But for the time being I just hope I could quickly locate the best one document to save the time.   I think there must be some existing summary on the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently reading http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf  which seems to be an excellent book introducing gaussian process.  If anyone knows better tutorials, welcome to put them here.